# php web service returning everything as a string

Tags: php

I have a very simple web service that makes a call to my mysql server and returns data. The problem is though that despite the field types on the database being set to the likes of `int`, `double` and `tinyint(1)` [`boolean`], when I serialise the returned values everything comes out as a `string`.

Is there a way to ensure the types are maintained from the mysql table?

I am serialising into a class that looks like this

```
class MyClassDTO
{
    public $my_int;
    public $my_double;
    public $my_bool;
}
```

I'm using PHP 5.6 (it's what my hosting provides, so I can't change over to 7), so from memory strongly typed variables aren't allowed.

The service is returning data which is always a good thing ;)

Comment: The first obvious diagnostic is to determine at which exact step data gets stringified, using a debugger or plain `var_dump()`'s.

Comment: MySQL only returns strings to PHP. But given that PHP is a weakly typed language, `"0" == 0` is true (the string of zero, and the integer of zero is equal), it shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: can you provide an example of the returned data and how are you serializing it ?

Comment: *"when I serialise the returned values everything comes out as a string"* ... isn't that pretty much the definition of serialising an object?

Comment: It looks to be that a value is being returned instead of true/false within the php, so is there a way to change 0 and 1 to the true/false value automagically?

Comment: Data doesn't get from MySQL to the internet tubes automagically, you've surely written code to make it happen. You need to change that code to behave the way you want—don't expect to fine-tune your app by changing configuration settings or something.